# matrix spectral representation

Tags: matrices, statistics

can you give me any idea how to show this?

Show that $A \ge I$ implies $A^{-1} \le I$, and use this result to deduce that $A\ge B\ge0$ implies 
$0\le A^{-1} \le B^{-1}$.

I think this question is related to spectral representation, but have no idea where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by A $\ge$ I?  Do you mean every element of A $\ge$ every element of I?  That all the eigenvalues of A are larger than 1?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.** When $A,B$ are positive definite,

- $x^\ast(I-A^{-1})x=(A^{-1/2}x)^\ast(A-I)(A^{-1/2}x)$,
- $A\succeq B\Leftrightarrow B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}\succeq I$.